# unable to access git remote repository

Tags: git, github

```
C:\Users\sai\Downloads\mycomputer\STUDY\CI\second>git remote add origin https://github.com/saikrishnamelam94/helloworld.git

    C:\Users\sai\Downloads\mycomputer\STUDY\CI\second>git push -u origin master
    remote: Permission to saikrishnamelam94/helloworld.git denied to saikrishnamelam.
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/saikrishnamelam94/helloworld.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

    C:\Users\sai\Downloads\mycomputer\STUDY\CI\second>
```

can any one tell me whats wrong here ?